# Why can't my django application send an email using Google App Engine and specified SMTP settings?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email

I wrote a django app, and it was sending email fine. I am now porting it to use it with Google App Engine, but it won't send for some reason. What's going on?
    *settings.py*

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

*views.py*

from google.appengine.api import mail
import webapp2

...

mail.send_mail(to="xxx@gmail.com", sender="test@test.com", subject="test", body="Hello World")
```

Nothing shows up! It's strange

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use, nor specify any old smtp server with app engine. You have to use the provided mail api. The emails will also appear to come from the admin of the application.

> The development web server can send email messages if configured to do
>   so with command-line options. It can use an SMTP server or the
>   Sendmail application, if available. **When your application is running
>   on App Engine, it uses the App Engine mail service to send email
>   messages**. See the Development Web Server for more information.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

Here's the example they give:

```py
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import users

    class InviteFriendHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user is None:
          login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
          self.redirect(login_url)
          return
        to_addr = self.request.get("friend_email")
        if not mail.is_email_valid(to_addr):
            # Return an error message...
            pass

        message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender = user.email()
        message.to = to_addr
        message.body = """
I've invited you to Example.com!

To accept this invitation, click the following link,
or copy and paste the URL into your browser's address
bar:

%s
        """ % generate_invite_link(to_addr)

        message.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails on Google App Engine is restricted, **only email addresses which belongs to project owners or developers** could be used.

and Django has it's own mechanism to send out email, for better integration, I will suggest you to use some Django library such as [Django Rocket Engine](https://github.com/xando/django-rocket-engine).

download the source code and put it under you App Engine project, deploy it and put this line in `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'rocket_engine.mail.EmailBackend'
```

after integrated that, you don't need to use GAE Email API by yourself, you just need to use the Django email API as usual, then emails got sent.